# Indexing documents in a network folder

Tags: windows, file-management, document-indexing

I'd love to have a tool that creates an index for documents in a windows network folder. I'm looking for a client-side only solution.

The index should contain the filenames and file content for common formats (like docx and pdf).

Any additional text mining and key word visualization features are welcome, too.

Comment: I'd love a general filesystem indexing application. It'd be nice if I could search an index of all of my not-currently-connected external hard drives.

Comment: I never thought to ask, but as my answer has no net upvotes, and there are no other answers currently, by "indexing" did you mean an index of document (file) names or, as I assumed, did you mean an index of the (text) contents of documents (files)?

Comment: Well, actually your answer has +1/-1 votes. I left the question open in hope of another candidate.

Comment: Other phrases for this kind of software are "disk cataloger", "disk catalog software", and "disk catalog organizer". I'm looking for one to use myself now.

Comment: @KennyEvitt: Please let me know about your progress and feel free to suggest an edit about the additional terms.

Comment: By `client-side only`, you mean *no* software installed & nothing done on the other computer other than using it as a network drive?

Answer (score 1):

[DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) will do what you specified.

There are native Windows and Mac OS versions, as well as a portable version that should work on any platform for which Java is available.

On Windows, you can index a network folder either as a mapped drive or via its UNC path.

I don't think it has any "text mining" or "key word visualization" features itself. But it's built on Apache Lucene, so I'd imagine you could use other tools with the indexes that DocFetcher creates.

The source code is freely available and licensed under the [Eclipse Public License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Public_License), tho [the project website](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php) states "Please note that due to lack of time we currently have no plans to extend DocFetcher in any significant way.".

Answer (score -1):

You can still use Google Desktop to do this; you can download it [here](http://google-desktop.en.softonic.com/) from Softonic. Just add the network drive in the list of *Search Locations* under the *Desktop Search* options.

You can also find numerous plugins for indexing different types of files. [Larry's Any Text File Indexer](http://www.trivex.net/) is great for indexing text files like code files that don't have a *.txt* extension.

Comment: A late thanks on that! Since GDS is discontinued since 2011, it does not tend to be the best candidate for a long-term solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never found any alternatives – and I've looked!